# Unfulfilled Promise From A Metamask Transaction

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

I'm having a problem with my JS code pausing on the `let result` line.

Metamask prompts me to approve the transaction initiated in the line (which I do), but then doesn't proceed any further.

As the `await` keyword forces the code to pause until the promise is fulfilled, it appears as if the promise is not being fulfilled.

```
handleButtonPress: async function(event) {

    console.log(1);

    let account = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log(account);

    let result = await App.contracts.Marketplace.methods.createStorefront('store2', 'shoe store2').send({from: account[0]});

    console.log(2);

}
```

Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: "it appears as if the promise is not being fulfilled" - how exactly does that appear? `console.log(2)` never executed? It might take some time if you're on a public network.

Comment: @goodvibration. I appreciate the question. As you correctly surmise, console.log(2) is never executed. To clarify, I'm using Ganache as a local blockchain, Metamask to connect to it, and lite-server. Cheers.

Comment: And what do you see on Ganache console?